# Python Add-On API: Constructing a new item on each execute()

Tags: python, add-on, operator

I have a simple operator (extending `bpy.types.Operator`) which I'm using as a button, and I intend to have it create a new cube each time execute() is called.

```
class NewCubeOperator(Operator): 
    bl_idname = "mesh.make_new_cube"
    bl_label = "New Cube"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context): 
        return True

    def execute(self, context): 
        print("Cube created!")
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
        return {"FINISHED"}

class ParentOperator(Operator): 
    [...]
    def draw(self, context): 
        layout.operator('mesh.make_new_cube', text='New Cube')

    def execute(self, context): 
        return {"FINISHED"}
```

Everything is displayed as I want, the button shows up and can be clicked, and that calls execute(), which then prints "Cube created!" to the console but no cubes appear.  Am I doing something wrong?  The same code works perfectly when done outside the context of an add-on.

I'm personally also  perplexed by how Blender requires you to re-create the mesh in full whenever you tweak a parameter and execute() is called on your add-on, would someone be willing to explain this?  (I suspect that has something to do with this)

Comment: It should create a cube as far as I can tell. Perhaps the view layer hasn't been update right away, it should appear in the outliner though. Blender doesn't require you to re-create a mesh, that is just because you've build your add-on this way. You can access existing objects and modify them as well.

Comment: IMO impossible to tell what the issue is from code posted. Please post stripped down, but working code of with emphasis on how (or why) you are using "parent" operator.